# Find a solution of $t\frac{dy}{dt}=t^2−t$ and determine a function $y(t)$ that passes through the given coordinates $(t, y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, education, nonlinear-system

Find a solution of $t\frac{dy}{dt}=t^2−t$ that passes through the points:

i) $(0, 1)$

ii) $(0, 0)$

iii) $(1/2, 1/2)$

iv) $(2, 1/4)$

SOS: I don't know where to start and my professor is no help.

Comment: Did you hear of variable separable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ty'=t^2-t$$
$$\frac {dy}{t-1}=\frac {dt}{1}$$
$$\frac {d(y+t)}{t}=\frac {dt}{1}$$

$${d(y+t)}=t {dt}$$
$$y+t=\frac {t^2}2+C$$
That passes through $(0,1)$ means  $(0,1)=(t,y) \implies y(0)=1$ 
You can deduce the value of the constant $C$

Comment: i)c=1, ii)c=0, iii)7/8=c iv)1/4=c

Comment: @TaljanaD Thats good ..

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: you're welcome @TaljanaD

Answer (score 1):

Go on dividing by $t$ on both sides of the differential equation and multiplying both sides by $dt$. Doing this, you get the following simplified differential equation:

$$dy=\frac{t^2-t}{t}dt$$
$$\Rightarrow dy=(t-1)dt$$

Now, Integrate both sides:

$$\int dy=\int (t-1)dt$$
$$\Rightarrow y=\frac{t^2}{2}-t+C$$

Further you are given a set of different intial values of the function $y(t)$ for which you have to figure out the value of the Constant of Integration, $C$. Hope you can proceed from here.

Cheers

Comment: So I plug in the points and then I'll find the value of C?

Comment: Exactly, You can confirm your results by plotting these functions in a graphing calculator and verifying whether the points really lie on the obtained $y(x)$

Comment: i)c=1, ii)c=0, iii)7/8=c iv)1/4=c

Comment: Those values do correspond with the given initial values. So you've got your functions $y(t)$